# Reference request: Textbook similar in structure to "Computational Materials Science: An Introduction" by June Lee for Computational Biology

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, computational-biology

In the *Computational Materials Science: An Introduction* by June Lee, he discusses molecular dynamics and density functional theory with examples from LAMMPS and QuantumEspresso, and explains LAMMPS and QuantumEspresso in detail.

I was wondering if there is a similar text in Computational Biology for molecular dynamics but in GROMACS/NAMD, I can use tutorials but I would like to find a textbook with more examples and explanations.

Comment: This might fit better on the new [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com). It focuses more specifically on molecular and material simulation, so you might find someone there who knows some MD. Or you may find an existing question with a suitable reference.

Comment: @Tyberius, thank you so much. I posted it there too.